# Intel Modin Jupyter notebook issues

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, intel-modin, intel-cloud

I have got two issues with modin

1. Lately I am not able to create modin environment using the command:

   `conda create -n aikit-modin intel-aikit-modin -c intel -c conda-forge`

(as mentioned in the documentation link of AI Analytics toolkit https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/installing-ai-kit-with-conda.html#gs.2irfv6 )

It seems documentation correction is required.

2. I was able to create modin environment using stock

   `conda create -n stock-modin modin -c conda-forge`

(referred-https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/distribution-of-modin.html#gs.2isi2d and Data Science at Scale with Modin documentation:

https://medium.com/intel-analytics-software/data-science-at-scale-with-modin-5319175e6b9a )

But while trying to do the modin sample, NYC_Taxi.ipynb, in the online JupyterLab of Intel devcloud, I am getting a

> file save server error JupyterHub server no longer running at
> /user/uXXXXX/api/contents/modin/examples/jupyter/NYC_Taxi.ipynb.
> Restart the server at
> http://jupyter.oneapi.devcloud.intel.com/hub/spawn/uXXXXX

as shown in the screenshot. I was not able to complete the notebook. It seems like a kernel error, even though I created a fresh kernel from the stock-modin environment.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxKdY.png)

(source of the NYC sample:https://github.com/modin-project/modin/tree/master/examples )

How to execute the samples of Intel Distribution of Modin? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `conda create -n aikit-modin intel-aikit-modin -c intel -c conda-forge`

This command takes time to execute. As you can create modin environment using stock, you can execute the notebook using the below method.

2. As a workaround, devcloud tunneling is a solution to this kernel error. Open terminals like `Cygwin`, `vscode`, `mobaxterm` or `openssh`. Setting up of devcloud connection should be done before going to the steps below. Please refer `Connect to the Devcloud` option in https://devcloud.intel.com/oneapi/documentation/shell-commands/

If you have connected to devcloud using any of the above terminals, please follow the below steps.

**In the first terminal execute the following commands**

```
ssh devcloud  //(To connect to devcloud)
qsub -I  //(to request compute node)
copy the compute node  //(it would be of this format sXXX-nXXX)
conda create -n stock-modin modin -c conda-forge  //(to create modin environment using stock)
source activate stock-modin  //(activate modin environment)
conda install pip
conda install ipykernel  //(package for creating kernels)
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"  //(command to create kernels)
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=<desired_port_number>  //(to launch Jupyter)
Copy any one of the URLs
“Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
http://localhost: <desired_port_number>/?token=2deea502bd258ed648f59eb11383bff4fd0edf5a4ce4f4f3or 
http://127.0.0.1: <desired_port_number>/?token=2deea502bd258ed648f59eb11383bff4fd0edf5a4ce4f4f3”
```

**Run the below commands in another terminal: (Keep the first terminal open)**

```
ssh -L <desired_port_number>:localhost: <desired_port_number> devcloud 
ssh -L <desired_port_number>:localhost: <desired_port_number> <compute node you copied>
```

1. Open the copied URL in a browser
2. You’ll get Jupyter, open the required notebook.
3. Select the kernel that you created
4. Execute the notebook.